# Which tool to use to manage a project?

Tags: tools, web-tools, agile

Some time ago I watched [these video casts](http://www.autumnofagile.net/), and I liked how the project was managed.

Is there a tool for linux similar to target process ([target process's webpage](http://targetprocess.com/Product.aspx))?
If not, what tool are you using for managing an agile project (linux, or cross platform)?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8808/what-is-the-best-agile-project-management-tool-have-you-used

Answer (score 2):

Two that I have used in the past with great success are:

- [Ralley](http://www.rallydev.com/)
- [Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com)

Both have free community versions.

Answer (score 1):

I use [fogbugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/). There is plugin for [agile](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/plugins/plugin.aspx?ixPlugin=3).

> The Project Backlog (often called the "Product Backlog") is central to Scrum and Agile project management practices. It's essentially a feature wish list sorted by order of implementation. 
>   The Project Backlog Plugin allows you to manage a backlog without ever leaving the FogBugz grid view. You can assign a case an order in the backlog just by clicking on the case's "Backlog" column, and when the grid view is sorted by Backlog, a set of arrow controls appear allowing you to move cases up or down in the order with the click of a mouse.

P.S. fugbugz is free for students and 1-2 persons team.

[Further more you may read about this topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693/how-do-you-use-fogbugz-with-an-agile-methodology).

Comment: Fogbugz is free for students and 1-2 person teams? Do you have a link for this? The only thing I was able to find listed $299 for one person.

Comment: Here you go http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/StudentAndStartup.html

Answer (score 1):

There are really many choices for local Linux hosted issue trackers/schedulers.  For personal projects, I am currently running Redmine (ruby runtime) using the Bitnami packaged stack for Windows, which made installation of the core product painless.  I've added a few plugins, one of which is backlog functionality, and while a little crude, is effective.  Other plugins have been somewhat problematic as I was evaluating it, especially in sorting out version dependencies.

An alternative I considered for locally hosted tracking of personal projects was Atlassian Jira (java runtime/container).